# Como convertir variable undefined o null a un Object

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

**Problema**: tengo una variable que cambia en función de si el usuario ha realizado login o no, esta se inicializa como `null` por lo general al no haber iniciado sesión, el problema lo tengo que al realizar iniciar sesión esta variable debe cambiar y el problema lo obtengo en que como esta esta en `null` no se puede convertir a un `Object` por lo menos de forma directa, he probado con `Object.assign()` y tampoco me funciona. La variable que cambia y me da el problema es `userIsLoged`.

## Código

```
    async function loginUser(credenciales, setUserInfo) {
    
      const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/Usuarios/?search=" + credenciales.usuario;
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const data = await response.data;
      
      if(data[0].nombre === credenciales.usuario){
        if(data[0].password === credenciales.password){
          setUserInfo(data[0].nombre);
          window.location.replace('/');
        }
        else{
          alert('Comprueba los datos introducidos');
        }
      }
      else{
        alert('Comprueba los datos introducidos');
      }
    }
    
    export default function Login() {
    
      const userInfo = React.useContext(userContext);
      const setUserInfo = React.useContext(setUserContext);
      const userIsLoged =(Object.keys(userInfo).length) ? Object.assign(userInfo.first +" "+ userInfo.last)  : null;
      
      const [usuario, setUsuario] = React.useState({});
      const [password, setPassword] = React.useState({});
    
      const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        await loginUser({
          usuario,
          password,
        }, setUserInfo);
      };
}
```

Comment: Y por que no lo iniciativas como False?

Comment: No creo que tú problema sea la variable `userIsLoged`. Yo creo que es `userInfo`. ¿Que mensaje de error te da?

Comment: ¿Y por que no inicializar la variable como `var objeto = { }`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich el mensaje de error que obtengo es el siguiente: ```Cannot convert undefined or null to object```

Comment: @SaulEspinozaLo he probado de esa manera y el error es el mismo.

Comment: Puedes verificar que te retorna  el `Object.keys`? Me parece que ahí está tu problema. ¿Estás seguro que `userInfo` no es nulo? Lo que pasa es que no creo que sea `userIsLoged` porque está variable primeramente no está en el lado derecho y solo va a recibir un valor sea nulo o cualquier otro. Por lo tanto, sospecho que `Object.keys` es quien dice que no puede convertir un objeto nulo o indefinido. Es el candidato con mayor probabilidad en que ocurra el error.  Estás bien seguro que `userInfo` tiene un valor correcto?  quitas el `Object.assign` el problema mismo cierto? Si es `Object.Keys`

Comment: Quítale el Object.assign porque tampoco está muy bien que digamos

Comment: Si inicializas `userContext` como  un objeto vacio `{}`, de tal forma que `userInfo` tome ese valor en el primer render de `Login` puede que funcione, pero dices que tampoco funciona? saludos

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich el `Object.keys` ahora me guarda el usuario el problema que tengo ahora es otro ya que no logro que se mantega por mucho tiempo el valor y en seguida vuelve a `null`.

Comment: @g.4 finalmente he optado por usar `userIsLoged` y pasar a usar `userInfo` directamente aunque creo que eso me genera, el problema mencionado antes.